# aggregate 2 dictionary items into an object

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, aggregate

I've got a dictionary with contains answers to a evaluation, as follows:

```
{
    {"question1", "7"},
    {"question1_comment", "pretty difficult"},
    {"question2", "9"},
    {"question2_comment", ""},
    {"question3", "5"},
    {"question3_comment", "Never on time"},
}
```

but I need to combine the score item with the comment item into an object as follows

```
{
    {"question1", "7", "pretty difficult"},
    {"question2", "9", ""},
    {"question3", "5", "Never on time"},
}
```

I think I need to use the Aggregate method to pull this off, but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Just loop through the items and construct a new instance of a custom object. What's the problem?

Comment: the problem is  i have no idea how to combine the proper items when looping through the dictionary.

sometimes I need to create a new item, sometimes i need to add to an already created item.

Comment: @TomOrton That's merging two or more dictionaries.  This is merging two entries from one dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var res = data
    .Keys
    .Where(s => !s.EndsWith("_comment"))
    .Select(s => new[] {s, data[s], data[s+"_comment"]})
    .ToList();
```

The ides is to first filter out all keys that do not end in `"_comment"`, and then use these keys to look up the two pieces of content into the resultant array.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/rojBEh)

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but maybe a good idea:

```
Regex r = new Regex("^question\\d$");
var result = myDict.Where(x => r.IsMatch(x.Key)).Select(x => new {
        Question = x.Key,
        Score = x.Value,
        Comment = myDict[x.Key + "_comment"]
});
```

The approach is the contrary one to that from DasBlinkenLight. You select all entries that fit the regex `^question\d$` (meaning all that end with a number). For those entries you create a new instance of an anonymous type, where the comment is retrieved by searching the appropriate item within the dictionary.

EDIT: alternatively to avoid the use of a Regex you can first filter by using

```
myDict.Where(x => !x.Key.EndsWith("_comment"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Checked below answer

```
        Dictionary<string, string> objstr = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        objstr.Add("question1", "7");
        objstr.Add("question1_comment", "pretty difficult");
        objstr.Add("question2", "9");
        objstr.Add("question2_comment", "");
        objstr.Add("question3", "5");
        objstr.Add("question3_comment", "Never on time");

        var Mainobj = objstr.Where(x => x.Key.Contains("_"));
        var obj = objstr.Where(x => x.Key.Contains("_") == false);
        var final = from objl in obj
                    join Mainobjl in Mainobj
                    on objl.Key equals Mainobjl.Key.Replace("_comment", "") into matching
                    select new
                    {
                        question = objl.Key,
                        rank = objl.Value,
                        comment = matching.FirstOrDefault().Value
                    };
        var obj11 = final.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create some struct for holding values for these questions, i.e:

```
public struct Question 
{
    public string QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

and build `List<Question >`:

```
var list = dict
    .Where(x => !x.Key.Contains("comment"))
    .Select(x => 
    new Question() 
    {
        QuestionId =x.Key, 
        Answer = x.Value, 
        Comment = dict.Single(y => 
            y.Key == String.Concat(x.Key,"_comment")).Value})
    .ToList();
```

[demo](http://ideone.com/kI13kj) - little bit faster than solution with list of tables